# Can Someone look at my Stored Procedure and tell me where i am going wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing an app and I'm generating a random order number in C# and before I do an insert statement I need to verify that there is no duplicate order number. This is my stored procedure (it's just a test procedure to help in figuring this out)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test$For$Dupes
   (@RandNum int)
AS
   declare @myNum int

   SELECT OrderNumber, COUNT(*) 
   FROM [TEST]
   WHERE OrderNumber = @RandNum

   IF(COUNT(*) < 1)
     SET @myNum = 0

   IF(COUNT(*) > 1)
     SET @myNum = 1
```

What I am trying to accomplish is if there is a duplicate I need to output a 1 and let my c# code regenerate a random number, and if there is no duplicate then I need an output of 0 so I can continue on my insert into my table.

I had this figured out a few years ago and can't find my code with how I did it, and now I am lost trying to figure this out. Any ideas?

It's not working just yet, I'm getting this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test$For$Dupes, Line 8
>   Column 'TEST.OrderNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is your question? Doesn't your code work?

Comment: Thanks...No, its not working I'm getting this error..
    Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test$For$Dupes, Line 8
    Column 'TEST.OrderNumber' is invalid in the select list   because   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Set the title properly... It should not be your personal message, it must specify the title of the question..

Comment: I just need to verify that the random generated order number is not duplicated in my table and if it is I need an output of 1 if there is and 0 if there isn't so I can handle it in my code

Comment: @Paritosh, you are right I should have been a little more clearer in the title

Comment: BTW: A relational database system hides uncommitted data from other transactions/sessions. This is called *transaction isolation*. For that reason, your approach can fail if new order numbers are inserted into the database by concurrent transactions (the more parallel transactions and the smaller your random number range, the more likely).

Comment: Why are you generating "random" order numbers?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little more efficient because it stops looking thru the table when it finds a match. And I think it is clearer.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Test$For$Dupes
    (
    @RandNum int
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [TEST] WHERE OrderNumber = @RandNum) 
         SELECT 1
    ELSE
         SELECT 0

    END
```

You would read this on the C# side like:

```
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Test$For$Dupes";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RandNum", 100);
        return (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    }
```

Comment: This one is doing the same when I run it when I pass an ordernumber that is not in the table and when I pass one that is in the table, keeps returning 0

Comment: I think you are reading the RETURN value where 0 means success. See my addition on what the C# code should look like.

Comment: ohhhhh ok, I see what you are saying maybe the reason why I keep getting a return of 0 is because i'm running the stored procedure in sql server management studio and not passing from the code? I'll give that a try

Comment: That's the thing I know what order numbers in my table and when I throw a number that's not in there I still receive a 0 and if it fails I still receive 0

Comment: No, if you are running it from SSMS you should see a 1 if you find a match. Review everything b/c this should work.

Comment: You are right it does work, I was reading everything wrong in ssms

Comment: i kept looking at the return value and not the results.

Comment: Thanks guys for jumping in helping me out with this it is much appreciated and everything worked properly from all of you guys and it was just me not looking at the right window. Out of all the forums, this one is the best, everyone helps out a lot faster :) Thanks again everyone!

Comment: By the way, I would just return the next available number to C# if there was a duplicate.  while exists (select 1 FROM ListItems WHERE ID = \@RandNum)
set \@RandNum = @RandNum + 1

select \@RandNum

Comment: I have another issue, do you have time to give me another hand?

Comment: What is your issue, you can just email me direct.

Comment: I figured out what my errors have been and I do appreciate the offer of letting me email. I spent 3 hours the other night trying to figure out why I wasn't able to pass a parameter, even after debugging. Then after I posted it, and nobody had noticed either and I took a look at the code again and realized I forgot a line of code which was,
    cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: JBrooks, I'm going to have to email you, I got this error and its something I haven't seen before..Where would I find your email address? I checked your profile but didn't see one. Thanks, I appreciate it and I can explain to you what i'm trying to accomplish and I need to send this code off today.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are trying to compare in if condition as `Count(*)` which is not a variable..
you need to declare a variable and set that variable in the query then compare that variable in an `if` condition. So if i rectify your code it will be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test$For$Dupes
(
@RandNum int
)
AS
Begin
declare @myNum int
declare @orderNoCount int

select @orderNoCount=COUNT(*) FROM [TEST]
WHERE OrderNumber = @RandNum

IF(@orderNoCount =< 1)
Set @myNum = 0
IF(@orderNoCount > 1)
SET @myNum = 1

END
```

> > in your code you are missing condition `when ordernumber = 1`... So I have added that condition too.

You can try this also:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test$For$Dupes
(
@RandNum int
)
AS
BEGIN

IF (select Count(Distinct OrderNumber) FROM [TEST] WHERE OrderNumber = @RandNum) >= 1
Set @myNum = 1
ELSE
SET @myNum = 0

END
```

Comment: With your firt example I am getting this error:
Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Test$For$Dupes, Line 10
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Comment: The second example, keeps returning 0. My table looks like this

TestID         OrderNumber
1              1
2              1
3              2
4              3
5              1

those are just values I put in to work with before I add the real random numbers. Sorry for the formatting looks like...The ordernumbers are 1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1

Comment: Oh!!.. i didn't add equal condition in my code too .. just add equal to sign "=" in line >> IF (select Count(Distinct OrderNumber) FROM [TEST] WHERE OrderNumber = @RandNum) >= 1

Comment: Sorry.. it was my mistake .. in first example u need to add group by clause... let me edit my comment ...

Comment: Same thing returning 0

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the `if..else` condition, you can just use the following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test$For$Dupes
(
@RandNum int
)
AS
BEGIN
declare @myNum int

SELECT @myNum = CASE COUNT(*)
    WHEN 0 THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END
FROM test
WHERE orderNumber = @RandNum
GROUP BY orderNumber

END
```

fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51a0e/22

Comment: This one keeps return 0, even when I pass an Order Number of 1 (which is in the table) or a 5 (which isn't in the table)

Comment: If I do plane select statement then the result is fine, you can see in the fiddle I have provided.